# IE11 browser showing document mode as 5(default)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

Im using bootstrap framework and using the follwoing docttype and meta tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

Here IE showing document mode as 5(default), mean while all the UI got disturbed, any solution for showing IE=edge.[image: Here is the screen shot]

Thanks

Comment: I'm in same situation, how you make it work, how did you set EDGE as default? Please share, it would be life saver for me..

Comment: no `<html><head>` tags ?

Answer (score 2):

Your IE options are probably set to display Intranet sites in Compatibility View. I tested IE 11 at the official Bootstrap site and it was set to Edge using X-UA meta tag.

From the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx): 
**Via intranet compatibility settings:** The "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" box is checked in the Compatibility View settings."